# Заменить слова в документе на переданные пользователем

Tags: php, html

берется простой документ с текстом и конвертируется в html после чего этот html отправляется клиенту и отображается на фронте, клиент помечает какие слова он хочет заменить и на что(причем если в документе два слова с одинаковым значением, должно меняться только то слово которое пометил пользователь, второе слово свое значение не меняет), после чего информация о том какие слова в html документе он хочет заменить отправляются на сервер, в сервере мы уже должны поменять нужные слова не в самом html, а в простом документе, то есть мы знаем позицию изменяемого слова в html, но не знаем позицию этого же слова в простом документе. Есть у кого идея как можно определить какие слова нужно поменять в документе зная позицию этих же слов в html документе?

Comment: `какие слова нужно поменять`  => `зная позицию этих же слов`. Вопрос по сути бессмысленный. Вы знаете позицию слова, но не знаете какое слово нужно заменить? А зачем тогда вообще нужна эта позиция?

Comment: Найти слова => Массив => Указать индексы => Отправить на сервер индексы => Найти слова в документе => Массив => Заменить слова по индексу.

Comment: вы не понимаете, когда документ экспортируется в html формат, в нем появляются тэги и соответственно одно и тоже слово в html документе будеет иметь одну позицию в другом другую относительно начала текста

Comment: @АндрейНовиков у вас есть текст с тегами. Юзер в нем ищет слово "корова", находит 5 слов - массив из 5 элементов. Юзер меняет 2 и 5 слово. В чем проблема найти второе и пятое слово "корова" в изначальном документе и заменить их? Кроме этого, какой смысл менять отрисованный с html документ или вы текстовый редактор делаете? Не проще поиск сразу выполнять в изначальном документе, а потом уже перерисовывать html? Если совсем не понятно, напишите, напишу подробный ответ.

Comment: Что-то типа source-map можно придумать.
Чем в экспортируется в html формат то?
Например, изначально обернуть слова span-ами с позициями в изначальном документе, а потом экспортировать дальше.

Comment: xydop, вот это первый метод который мне пришел в голову, но он дико неоптимизированный, я просто думал что есть методы поумнее)

Comment: Sergei Kirjanov, я использую google api drive, а там какая-то своя непростая логика обертываения в  html)